# WebAPI and MVC application security credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have two applications - mvc web application for users to enter data and a telerik reporting webapi application. These are two separate sites hosted on the IIS. For both these applications, windows authentication is enabled. We created a role manager that would retrieve roles and userID for the current user from sql. I want this logic to be shared across both these applications. What's the best way to do that?

Does it make sense to use a WCF Authentication Service and create a cookie and share that between the two applications? If so, could you point me in the direction of that? Eventually, I would like for mobile applications we create to also be able to consume the same service.

I keep hearing that the webapi should not be in a different application... That it should be hosted by the main mvc application. We need to make sure that a new release of the reports does not force us to release a new version of the main application. There needs to be a separation of these two. Am I thinking through this the wrong way?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: If you want to share the same logic you can just move it into a shared class library. Is this an internal (intranet) application?

Comment: yeah it is an intranet application. Everything is. The role provider can't be shared between applications, right? We implemented a custom role provider and store that in the session for the mvc application. The webapi needs to be able to something similar. But if either one is authenticated, I don't want to have to go to the db again to authenticate for the other. I want it to be seamless between the two applications and share the logic for both.